# How to work with Type-Safe Builders in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've seen lots of tutorials but still didn't get exactly how it works. I understood the main idea: a function holding functions with data, but looking [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) I couldn't realize how and where the data is stored and who calls the function responsible for its storaging. Other tutorials seems to show just a snippet of code, which didn't help me much. Can you give me a full and simple example with a trivial class, like a person, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was interested in some details, too. Here's what I wrote:

```
data class Person(
        var name: String? = null,
        var age: Int? = null,
        val children: MutableList<Person> = ArrayList()
) {
    fun child(init: Person.() -> Unit) = Person().also {
        it.init()
        children.add(it)
    }
}

fun person(init: Person.() -> Unit) = Person().apply { init() }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = person {
        name = "Mommy"
        age = 33
        child {
            name = "Gugu"
            age = 2
        }
        child {
            name = "Gaga"
            age = 3
        }
    }
    println(p)
}
```

It prints out (with a little formatting added):

```
Person(name=Mommy, age=33, children=[
    Person(name=Gugu, age=2, children=[]), 
    Person(name=Gaga, age=3, children=[])
])
```

Comment: So, inside fun child, when you call child.init(), name = "Gugu" and age = 2 (written in main) is the same as writing child.name = "Gugu" and child.age = 2 in fun child, right?

Comment: Yes, because inside the `init` block, `this` is assigned to the `child` instance.

Comment: So function person is only for building purposes? If want to get some value after building, I would have to call Person class, right?

Comment: Yes, you get a regular data class out of it. But at any later point you can again call `p.child { ... }`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Kotlin DSLs

Kotlin is great for writing your own **Domain Specific Languages**, also called [type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html). Anko is one of the examples using such DSLs. The most important language feature you need to understand here is called ["Function Literals with Receiver"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), which you made use of already: `Test.() -> Unit`

### Function Literals with Receiver - Basics

Kotlin supports the concept of “function literals with receivers”. This enables us to call methods on the **receiver** of the function literal in its body *without any specific qualifiers*. This is very **similar to extension functions**in which it’s also possible to access members of the receiver object inside the extension.

A simple example, also one of the greatest functions in the Kotlin standard library, is`apply`

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

As you can see, such a function literal with receiver is taken as the argument `block` here. This block is simply executed and the receiver (which is an instance of `T`) is returned. In action this looks as follows:

```
val foo: Bar = Bar().apply {
    color = RED
    text = "Foo"
}
```

We instantiate an object of `Bar` and call `apply` on it. The instance of `Bar` becomes the “receiver”. The `block`, passed as an argument in `{}`(lambda expression) does not need to use additional qualifiers to access and modify the shown visible properties `color` and `text`.

### Function Literals with Receiver - in DSL

If you look at this example, taken from the documentation, you see this in action:

```
class HTML {
    fun body() { ... }
}

fun html(init: HTML.() -> Unit): HTML {
    val html = HTML()  // create the receiver object
    html.init()        // pass the receiver object to the lambda
    return html
}


html {       // lambda with receiver begins here
    body()   // calling a method on the receiver object
}
```

The `html()` function expects such a function literal with receiver with `HTML` as the receiver. In the function body you can see how it is used: an instance of `HTML` is created and the `init` is called on it.

### Benefit

The caller of such an *higher-order function* expecting a function literal with receiver (like `html()`) you can use any visible `HTML` function and property without additional qualifiers (like `this` e.g.), as you can see in the call:

```
html {       // lambda with receiver begins here
    body()   // calling a method on the receiver object
}
```

### Example

I've written a sample DSL and described it in a [blog post](https://kotlinexpertise.com/create-dsl-with-kotlin/). Maybe that's also helpful.

Comment: The blog post link seems to be dead

Answer (score 0):

Just to add other syntaxe

```
data class QCMBean(var qcmId : Int=-1, var question : String = "", var answers : ArrayList<AnswerBean> = ArrayList()) {

    companion object {
        fun qcm(init:QCMBean.()->Unit) = QCMBean().apply {
            init()
        }
    }
    fun answer(answer:String = "") = AnswerBean(answer).apply {
        answers.add(this)
    }
}
data class AnswerBean(var answer:String = "")


 qcm {
        qcmId = 1
        question = "How many cat ?"
        answer("1")
        answer("2")
    }
```